# polynomial surface fit numpy

Tags: numpy, polynomial-math

How do I fit a 2D surface `z=f(x,y)` with a polynomial in numpy with full cross terms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is inherently numerically ill-conditioned but you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(500)
y = np.random.randn(500)
z = np.random.randn(500) # Dependent variable

v = np.array([np.ones(500), x, y, x**2, x * y, y**2])

coefficients, residues, rank, singval = np.linalg.lstsq(v.T, z)
```

The more terms you add, the worse things get, numerically. Are you sure you want a polynomial interpolant?

There are other bases for polynomials for which the matrix of values is not so badly conditioned but I can't remember what they are called; any college-level numerical analysis textbook would have this material, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `polyvander2d` and `polyval2d`, but will need to do the fit yourself using the design matrix output from `polyvander2d`, probably involving scaling and such. It should be possible to build a class `Polynomial2d` from those tools.